# 90% CPU used by Ubuntu One

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-one

On my laptop (Ubuntu 10.04), the daemon ubuntuone-syncdaemon uses more than 90% of CPU. Even if I stop the synchronization. The only way to stop this is to sigkill the daemon ; but, obviously, my files are not synchronized and I obtain a lot of "conflict" files.

Could you give me a clue to stop this problem ?

Thank-you!

Gilles

Comment: Are you trying to sync a lot of files (thousands)? If so, the local scan process on versions earlier than Ubuntu 11.04 can be very resource intensive.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use U1 on Windows too? I had have this problem when syncing my files with Ubuntu an the Beta Version of Windows U1 Client.

Comment: No. My laptop is under Ubuntu 10.04 and my Desktop under Ubuntu 10.10. I have completely given up Windows since... a long time!

Comment: Alright :) Could you check the right of the synced files? Maybe there are some where root is owner.

Answer (score 0):

1. Report it as a bug similar to 488232, 407762 and 461963
   Really high CPU and growing memory usage by syncdaemon
2. Run a Diagnostic program found here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RomanYepishev/UbuntuOne/Diagnostics

To run diagnostics use the following commands:

wget http://ubuntuone-client-diagnose.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ubuntuone-client-diagnose.py
python ubuntuone-client-diagnose.py

There will be an **output and a solution** to the issue